# Trabalhando com o GitHub

Tags: git, github, versionamento

Estamos com um projeto de criar um servidor de aplicação baseado em J2EE + GlassFish, a fim de atualizar a maneira como trabalhamos na nossa empresa.

Nesse ambiente, dois programadores trabalharão no mesmo projeto, e escolhemos o Git como ferramenta de versionamento.

A minha dúvida é: Para utilizar o Git, eu crio uma conta para cada programador + uma conta para o servidor? Dai uso uma conta apenas como repositório do projeto? Sou leigo para utilizar sistema de versionamento, já li bastante mas ainda não entrou a ideia direito na minha cabeça.

Comment: Acho que um bom caminho a percorrer seria vasculhando as [perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github?sort=votes&pageSize=50) já feitas aqui no site, tem bastante conteúdo que pode esclarecer melhor o funcionamento

Comment: A duvida é sobre github ou sobre Git? Vai ser github mesmo ou vc vai criar repositórios locais com um master local? Ou esta usando Github privado?

Comment: Um guia para quem quer começar a usar Git (independente de github, bitbucket, gitlad, etc), esta dividido em tópicos: [git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide), não adianta muito uma ferramenta sem saber usa-la né? Se for implementar em sua empresa e não tiver noção de como usa-la acho que irá ter mais problemas que soluções.

Comment: Obrigado a todos que me ajudaram. Estou vasculhando quando estou com tempo de sobra no serviço, tentando absorver o máximo de coinhecimento.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento
Nós usaríamos um GitHub privado. A principio teremos liberdade para trabalhar nesse quesito aqui dentro da empresa, podendo testar e reavaliar livremente. Não sou louco de implementar algo que não tenho conhecimento em uma base de produção hehehe. Mas muito obrigado pelo retorno e a disponibilidade em responder.

Comment: Por isso mesmo indiquei o link/material com os tópicos para iniciar no "Git", tem muita gente que conheço no site que ficam reclamando por exemplo que não dá pra fazer commit diretamente no master e como contornar isto, mas contornar isto é o mesmo que "matar" o fundamento básico de controle do Git e do Versionamento, que controla o Master sempre é uma (ou mais pessoas) e outros funcionários fazem cópias e enviam geralmente como pull-request para que os "masters" avaliem. Pra fazer a verdade tenho certeza que tem empresas que permitem qualquer um fazer commit no "master".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O ideal é ter uma conta para a empresa, não para o servidor. Se mais pra frente a empresa tiver outros projetos, vocês podem criar um repositório por projeto.

Com uma única conta para a empresa vocês podem depois utilizar coisas legais como o Jenkins ou Hudson, que são ferramentas que ajudam na automatização de diversas tarefas e que se integram com sistemas de controle de versão.

Quanto a versionamento ser complicado de entender, na minha experiência as pessoas só entendem de verdade após usar e sentir na prática as vantagens que isso traz.

Comment: Concordo 1000% com essa afirmação: **Quanto a versionamento ser complicado de entender, na minha experiência as pessoas só entendem de verdade após usar e sentir na prática as vantagens que isso traz.**

Comment: Entendi. Essa questão de prática eu concordo plenamente também, obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Para utilizar GIT, não necessariamente precisa ser com Github, existem outras plataformas que disponibilizam o GIT como controle de Versão, como o Bitbucket, Gitlab, Visual Studio Team Services.

Assim como o Renan disse em outra resposta, você pode usar uma série de outras ferramentas, como ele mesmo citou, Jenkins, Hudson, etc..

Eu conheço muito do Visual Studio Team Services, e por isso a minha sugestão a você é a utilização desta ferramenta, pelos seguintes pontos:

1. É Online, gratuito para 5 desenvolvedores e ilimitados Stackholders
2. Você pode criar gratuitamente ilimitados repositórios para seus códigos fontes, seja utilizando TFVC ou GIT;
3. Você pode gerenciar seus backlogs e integrar com suas alterações no código fonte;
4. Você pode ter também processos de build automatizada, com validações de testes, arquiteturas, qualidade, etc;
5. Você pode ter processos de Deployment automatizado também.
6. Pode criar um Wiki para seu projeto

Essas funções acima, você pode utilizar de forma gratuita no VSTS no caso com até 5 desenvolvedores. 
Você pode também, pagando a parte, ter seu servidor nuget e npm privados.

O Bacana, é que tudo isso funciona não só para tecnologias Microsoft, você pode gerenciar por exemplo seu projeto Java, automatizar builds, e Deployment das aplicações Java, inclusive utilizando servidores linux para build e/ou destino de deployment.

Sobre aprender git, existe muito material bom na internet, como por exemplo:

- [Git para Iniciantes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMhskLXJuq4)

Caso queira conhecer mais sobre o VSTS, eu tenho uma playlist no meu canal sobre o assunto

- [Primeiros Passos com VSTS](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMFPOLE2cW1wynLrJqkAyfvCxRKsOqX-w)
- [Java com VSTS](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMFPOLE2cW1zn-_b7MahptaHJ04PaKYNt)